# Centos 7, apache logging zend_mm_heap corrupted and websites returning no response

Tags: php, apache

I have a server in the office that's used as a development server. It's running Centos 7 with Apache, PHP and MySQL.

Randomly some web applications on the server has stopped returning a response, and upon inspecting the Apache error log, I'm seeing this error when no response is received;

> zend_mm_heap corrupted

I've done some research and understand this has something to do with Zends memory management, but I don't seem to be able to find a way to resolve the issue.

I have checked my php.ini file, and cannot see any reference to APC so don't believe it's causing the issue.

The server was running fine, and it's pretty random that this has started, I don't believe we've changed anything on the server to cause the issue.

This error appears across multiple projects, so I confident that it's not project specific and more something relating to the server/software itself.

If I add the following to a projects .htaccess file, then it seems the web application works fine and no errors are generated. However I don't believe adding this to every project on my server is a suitable solution and I definitely thing there an issue somewhere, maybe bad ram?

```
php_flag opcache.enable Off
```